# lock free concurrency example; why is it not safe?

Tags: c++, concurrency, lock-free

I am trying to learn about concurrency in C++ and in doing so I am experimenting to see what works and what does not work. The example below is not well designed and I know there are much better ways of designing it but I would like to know why it seems that thread 1 and thread 2 are able to overwrite each other in the shared array. I thought the operations to the shared `flag_atomic` variable with the acquire/release semantics above and below the loading and writing of the shared `idx_atomic` index would prevent thread 1 and thread 2 retrieving the same index values regardless of the `idx_atomic` operation memory tags?

For reference I am using MSVC and x64.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;    // for ""ms operator

const size_t c_size = 40;
std::vector<int> shared_array;
std::atomic<bool> sync_start_atomic = false;
std::atomic<bool> flag_atomic = false;
std::atomic<size_t> idx_atomic = 0;


void thread1_x() {
    bool expected_flag = false;
    size_t temp_idx = 0;
    while (!sync_start_atomic.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (c_size / 2); ++i) {
        while (flag_atomic.compare_exchange_weak(expected_flag, true, std::memory_order_acq_rel, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                expected_flag = false;
        }
        temp_idx = idx_atomic.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        idx_atomic.store((temp_idx + 1), std::memory_order_relaxed);
        flag_atomic.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        shared_array[temp_idx] = i;

    }
}

void thread2_x() {
       bool expected_flag = false;
    size_t temp_idx = 0;
    while (!sync_start_atomic.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (c_size / 2); ++i) {
        while (flag_atomic.compare_exchange_weak(expected_flag, true, std::memory_order_acq_rel, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            expected_flag = false;
        }
        temp_idx = idx_atomic.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        idx_atomic.store((temp_idx + 1), std::memory_order_relaxed);
        flag_atomic.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        shared_array[temp_idx] = i + 100;

    }
}

void main(){
    shared_array.reserve(c_size);
    shared_array.assign(c_size, 0);
    std::thread tn_1(thread1_x);
    std::thread tn_2(thread2_x);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(60ms);
    sync_start_atomic.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    tn_1.join();
    tn_2.join();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < c_size; ++i) {
        std::cout << shared_array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Example real output:

100, 1, 101, 2, 3, 102, 4, 103, 104, 6, 106, 8, 108, 9, 10, 109, 11, 110, 12, 111, 14, 112, 113, 16, 17, 18, 115, 19, 116, 117, 118, 119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

Example expected output:

0, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 1, 2, 114, 3, 115, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 116, 16, 117, 17, 118, 18, 119, 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example output indicates that both threads are accessing the `idx_atomic` concurrently, which indicates a problem with your `flag_atomic` loop.  The condition check you are using is backwards.  `compare_exchange_weak` will return the result of the `flag_atomic == expected_flag` comparison - in other words, it returns `true` when the value is updated.  Since you want to exit the loop when this happens, the comparison should be

```
while (!flag_atomic.compare_exchange_weak(expected_flag, true, std::memory_order_acq_rel, std::memory_order_acquire))
```

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense :). I would mark your answer as the answer but i am new to this and don't know how?

Comment: @JoeOram: click the checkbox under the up/down vote arrows.

Comment: I like to think of `compare_exchange` functions as returning `true` when they succeed (i.e. when they do the store).  Because that's why you're using them, not for the compare per-se, but as a store that requires you to provide what you think the old value is.  So I would have picked different wording for the 2nd half of your first paragraph.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've reworded that a bit.

Comment: I was curious, does the way I described it match how you think about it yourself?  Or do you really think about it more in terms of the `==` comparison?  (actually bitwise equality including any padding, or `+0.0` vs. `-0.0`, which is sometimes different from `==`).

Comment: @PeterCordes I haven't had to use this much.  I was going mostly based on how the C++ standard describes it, along with a bit of experimentation with OP's code.